# QTableView - how to highlight only text with color (not entire cell)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt6, pyqt6

I would like to for some of the columns in my QTableView give color highlight to the text without filling the rest of the cell with color. This image shows exactly what I want:

[image]

What is the best way to do this? One option is to create each text value as an image externally and then set it as an icon (I know how to do that from other SO posts). But is there a better way?

I will do this for quite many tables / columns with many different values so I would need to create many images if I use icons. So it would be great if there is a way to instead write the text in the QTableView and somehow apply the color background so that it covers the text only.

Is it possible to e.g. paint that background using an item delegate somehow? Has someone done something similar with item delegates before and that can share an example of how it's done? I'm very new to Qt.

I'm using PyQt6.

Comment: Just use an [item delegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemdelegate.html) as you've already suggested yourself.

Comment: OK, I'm very new to Qt so that's why I was not sure if it's possible. But if you are sure it is, I will pursue that option.

Comment: Use a delegate and paint the text using the QTextDocument interface, which allows setting background colors.

Comment: I would not advice using `QTextDocument` if your use cases are as simple as those in the picture. You can use `QPainter` and paint a properly sized colored rectangle and a text inside it. Use `QFontMetrics` t get a bounding rectangle of the given text. But you will definitely need to implement the item delegate by overriding `QStyledItemDelegate`. It is not easy for beginner, be prepared for some struggle.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input. I will consider both options.